# Why does using super(qualifications) in a subclass throw a ReferenceError when it was defined in the superclass?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, subclass, superclass

```js
class SchoolEmployee {
  constructor(name, qualifications) {
    this._name = name;
    this._qualifications = qualifications;
    this._holidaysLeft = 21;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  get qualifications() {
    return this._qualifications;
  }

  get holidaysLeft() {
    return this._holidaysLeft;
  }

  takeHolidays(days) {
    this._holidaysLeft -= days;
  }
}

class Teacher extends SchoolEmployee {
  constructor(name, qualifications, subject) {
    super(name);
    super(qualifications); //THIS IS THE ERROR
    this._subject = subject;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  get qualifications() {
    return this._qualifications;
  }

  get subject() {
    return this._subject;
  }
}

let John = new Teacher('John', ['Maths', 'Physics'], 'Maths');
```

SchoolEmployee is the super class where I have defined what 'qualifications' is. From my knowledge, writing super(qualifications) calls the constructor of the super class where it was previously defined. Currently I am learning Javascript and i don't understand what went wrong. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: `ReferenceError: this is not defined
    at new Teacher (D:\MAIN\COding\javascript\classes.js:28:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\MAIN\COding\javascript\classes.js:45:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can look up [on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) super() calls the constructor of the parent class and you are calling it twice. What you probably want is

```
class Teacher extends SchoolEmployee {
    constructor(name, qualifications, subject) {
        super(name, qualifications);
        this._subject = subject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SchoolEmployee constructor expects 2 parameters you call the super with only one parameter. Try:

```
super(name, qualifications);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says `Super constructor may only be called once`. [Super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) calls the constructor and as the parent constructor accepts both `name, qualifications` pass them in one `super`.

```js
class SchoolEmployee {
  constructor (name, qualifications) {
    this._name = name;
    this._qualifications = qualifications;
    this._holidaysLeft = 21;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  get qualifications() {
    return this._qualifications;
  }

  get holidaysLeft() {
    return this._holidaysLeft;
  }

  takeHolidays(days) {
    this._holidaysLeft -= days;
  }
}

class Teacher extends SchoolEmployee {
  constructor (name, qualifications, subject) {
    super(name, qualifications);
    this._subject = subject;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  get qualifications() {
    return this._qualifications;
  }

  get subject() {
    return this._subject;
  }
}

let John = new Teacher('John',['Maths', 'Physics'],'Maths');
```